# RVIZ: URDF Model disappears when loaded

Tags: rviz, urdf, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to load a simple urdf model into rviz.  However, when rviz loads, the model is there for a split second, then disappears.  All the status read ok, and rviz shows no problems.  I can make the model appear, but only if I change the fixed frame to something non-existent, which then produces many issues.  The terminal ready no issues either.  I've already tried a common solution to export LC_NUMERIC to en_US.UTF-8, but this doesn't fix the issue.

I'm running ROS Melodic on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS through a Virtualbox VM on my Lenovo ideapad 330S (Windows 10).

[image: image description]

**RVIZ Config File:**

```
Panels:
  - Class: rviz/Displays
    Help Height: 78
    Name: Displays
    Property Tree Widget:
      Expanded:
        - /Status1
        - /RobotModel1/Links1
        - /TF1
      Splitter Ratio: 0.5
    Tree Height: 416
  - Class: rviz/Selection
    Name: Selection
  - Class: rviz/Tool Properties
    Expanded:
      - /2D Pose Estimate1
      - /2D Nav Goal1
      - /Publish Point1
    Name: Tool Properties
    Splitter Ratio: 0.5886790156364441
  - Class: rviz/Views
    Expanded:
      - /Current View1
    Name: Views
    Splitter Ratio: 0.5
  - Class: rviz/Time
    Experimental: false
    Name: Time
    SyncMode: 0
    SyncSource: ""
Preferences:
  PromptSaveOnExit: true
Toolbars:
  toolButtonStyle: 2
Visualization Manager:
  Class: ""
  Displays:
    - Alpha: 0.5
      Cell Size: 1
      Class: rviz/Grid
      Color: 160; 160; 164
      Enabled: true
      Line Style:
        Line Width: 0.029999999329447746
        Value: Lines
      Name: Grid
      Normal Cell Count: 0
      Offset:
        X: 0
        Y: 0
        Z: 0
      Plane: XY
      Plane Cell Count: 10
      Reference Frame: <Fixed_Frame>
      Value: true
    - Alpha: 1
      Class: rviz/RobotModel
      Collision Enabled: false
      Enabled: true
      Links:
        All Links Enabled: true
        Expand Joint Details: false
        Expand Link Details: false
        Expand Tree: false
        Link Tree Style: Links in Alphabetic Order
        back_left:
          Alpha: 1
          Show Axes: false
          Show Trail: false
          Value: true
        back_right:
          Alpha: 1
          Show Axes: false
          Show Trail: false
          Value: true
        chassis:
          Alpha: 1
          Show Axes: false
          Show Trail: false
          Value: true
        front_left:
          Alpha: 1
          Show Axes: false
          Show Trail: false
          Value: true
        front_right:
          Alpha: 1
          Show Axes: false
          Show Trail: false
          Value: true
      Name: RobotModel
      Robot Description: robot_description
      TF Prefix: ""
      Update Interval: 0
      Value: true
      Visual Enabled: true
    - Class: rviz/TF
      Enabled: true
      Frame Timeout: 15
      Frames:
        All Enabled: true
        back_left:
          Value: true
        back_right:
          Value: true
        base_link:
          Value: true
        chassis:
          Value: true
        front_left:
          Value: true
        front_right:
          Value: true
      Marker Scale: 1
      Name: TF
      Show Arrows: true
      Show Axes: true
      Show Names: true
      Tree:
        base_link:
          chassis:
            back_left:
              {}
            back_right:
              {}
            front_left:
              {}
            front_right:
              {}
      Update Interval: 0
      Value: true
  Enabled: true
  Global Options:
    Background Color: 48; 48; 48
    Default Light: true
    Fixed Frame: chassis
    Frame Rate: 30
  Name: root
  Tools:
    - Class: rviz/Interact
      Hide Inactive Objects: true
    - Class: rviz/MoveCamera
    - Class: rviz/Select
    - Class: rviz/FocusCamera
    - Class: rviz/Measure
    - Class: rviz/SetInitialPose
      Theta std deviation: 0.2617993950843811
      Topic: /initialpose
      X std deviation: 0.5
      Y std deviation: 0.5
    - Class: rviz/SetGoal
      Topic: /move_base_simple/goal
    - Class: rviz/PublishPoint
      Single click: true
      Topic: /clicked_point
  Value: true
  Views:
    Current:
      Class: rviz/Orbit
      Distance: 2.1567115783691406
      Enable Stereo Rendering:
        Stereo Eye Separation: 0.05999999865889549
        Stereo Focal Distance: 1
        Swap Stereo Eyes: false
        Value: false
      Focal Point:
        X: 0
        Y: 0
        Z: 0
      Focal Shape Fixed Size: true
      Focal Shape Size: 0.05000000074505806
      Invert Z Axis: false
      Name: Current View
      Near Clip Distance: 0.009999999776482582
      Pitch: 0.17539839446544647
      Target Frame: <Fixed Frame>
      Value: Orbit (rviz)
      Yaw: 0.8203979730606079
    Saved: ~
Window Geometry:
  Displays:
    collapsed: false
  Height: 713
  Hide Left Dock: false
  Hide Right Dock: false
  QMainWindow State: 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
  Selection:
    collapsed: false
  Time:
    collapsed: false
  Tool Properties:
    collapsed: false
  Views:
    collapsed: false
  Width: 957
  X: 67
  Y: 27
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379024/rviz:-urdf-model-disappears-when-loaded/) by [JoelB](https://answers.ros.org/users/60849/joelb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2021-05-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Stupid Problem.  Had alpha on material set to zero, so everything was just invisible.  That was fun...

---

Originally posted by [JoelB](https://answers.ros.org/users/60849/joelb/) with karma: 31 on 2021-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0